# Flickering on page load when using CSS breakpoints

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, padding

I have an item on a site that uses padding left: 32px in the main css. Then further down in the CSS I've got a conditional for when the viewport is less than 875 pixels, which then reduces the padding left of the same item to 20px.

The problem is that when the page loads the item in questions seems to load in the 20px position first, then realise the screen is more than 875px wide and move the item to the 32px position. The result of this is that the item appears to flicker which is obviously not what we want.

Any ideas what's going on and how to get around it?

Comment: can you post your codes here or fiddle it?

Comment: Let me guess? Is it happening on ie8 using polyfill for window size? Or are those two css in different files?

Comment: can you post ur media queries atlest?

Comment: Sure, here you go... http://jsfiddle.net/x3bo9L1h/

Comment: Maciej Paprocki: It's not actually, it's in Firefox (Chrome appears to be ok)